# If $a+b+c=0$ then $(\frac{a}{b-c}+\frac{b}{c-a}+\frac{c}{b-a})(\frac{b-c}{a}+\frac{c-a}{b}+\frac{a-b}{c})=9$

Tags: inequality

The problem is as stated in the title. There is the obvious condition that no two are equal. I tried to do this without using brute force and do all the multiplications. There must be a simple way to solve this but it escapes me. This is not even an inequality but I don't know how to classify it.

Comment: The last fraction in the first term should be $\dfrac{c}{a-b}$

Answer (score 2):

substituting $c=-a-b$ in the left side of the given term we get
$\left( {\frac {a}{2\,b+a}}+{\frac {b}{-2\,a-b}}+{\frac {-a-b}{b-a}}
 \right)  \left( {\frac {2\,b+a}{a}}+{\frac {-2\,a-b}{b}}+{\frac {a-b
}{-a-b}} \right) 
$ simplifing this we obtain $9$.

Comment: Nice solution!  =)

Comment: thanks you are welcome, waiting for your next problem

Comment: The result will follow but there are too many calculations. I was hoping for something shorter but probably there is no way around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$a=-b-c$

then $(\frac{-b-c}{b-c}+\frac{b}{c+b+c}+\frac{c}{b+b+c})(\frac{b-c}{-b-c}+\frac{c+b+c}{b}+\frac{-b-c-b}{c})$

$=(\frac{-b-c}{b-c}+\frac{b}{2c+b}+\frac{c}{2b+c})(\frac{b-c}{-b-c}+\frac{2c+b}{b}+\frac{-2b-c}{c})$

$= 9$

Comment: This is essentially the same as Dr. Graubner's solution... =)

Comment: yes, his solution appeared while I was typing mine

Comment: Both expressions cannot be 3. Probably you took a shortcut knowing that the result will follow. The problem is that there are still too many calculations but I guess there is no way around it. Thnx.

Comment: yes, used the help of wolfram alpha ;)

Comment: That definitely is a shortcut :) Maybe there is no elegant and short proof to this problem.